Breakdown software RAID0
I have a 5 drive RAID 0 array of non-important data (it's not a big deal if they are corrupted/lost, but I would rather not).
I want to destroy my RAID 0 drive by drive to then format them into RAID 0 btrfs by copying data one drive after the other.
Is there a way to do that on mdadm, moving stripes of a drive on others and then remove this drive from the array?

What research have you done and what have you tried? MDADM is a pretty mature product, and I'd guess that there are guides on removing disks from an existing array.

I found plenty of resources on how to remove disks from arrays, but not RAID 0 or not while keeping data. Pretty much everyone was clear "You can't" but, I can't see why in theory this can't be possible

The resources you found are right, because of RAID0.
RAID 0 is the stripe array, where the entire purpose is speed, or possibly size. In a RAID 0 there is no parity information, no redundancy, no fault tolerance.
Remove a single drive from a RAID 0 and you have lost all the data on the array.
Your only solution remove a drive from a RAID 0 is to backup all the data on that array to a different storage, remove the drive, and create a new array. Choosing RAID 5 or 6, which do striping but include parity, redundancy, and therefore some fault tolerance, would allow you to remove a drive while maintaining some recoverability.

I believe I've seen RAID controllers which support re-striping of some modes – is RAID0 reshaping not supported by mdadm software raid?
